# Adding unique IDs to mutiple polygons using loop or apply function in R

Tags: r, loop, unique-id

I want to add a unique ID (row number) for each polygon in a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame. I am new at working with spatial data (and programming). The goal is to merge all polygons belonging to a single species.

This is what I run:

```
setwd("~/type1")
species <- 'speciesX'
list_shp <- list.files(path=species, pattern="*.shp", full.names = TRUE,
                   recursive = TRUE, include.dirs = FALSE)
shp_objects <- lapply(list_shp, function(x) {readOGR(dsn=x, layer=ogrListLayers(x))})

# See the row names (IDs)
lapply(shp_objects, function(x) row.names(x@data))

# Manually set unique row names (IDs)
shp_objects[[1]] <- spChFIDs(shp_objects[[1]], as.character(10)) # e.g. 10
```

But, since the SPDF for each species can have several polygons, I tried making a for loop, implementing a simple counter, adding a consecutive number to each as row names (IDs) using the `spChFIDs` function.

```
idx<-0
for(i in shp_objects){
 idx<-idx+1
 shp_objects <- spChFIDs(i, as.character(idx))
}
```

When running this, and then `lapply(shp_objects, function(x) row.names(x@data))` to see if the row names have been updated accordingly, I get the error:

```
Error in as.list.default(X) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

How could I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question as it stands is confused, ambiguous and is not reproducible. If it had been reproducible we would have been able to resolve it in minutes rather than in days. (Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in its entirety as it is relevant to this GIS forum as well as to Stack Overflow.)

Essentially you were doing the right thing with the shapefiles, but your loop was not assigning values properly. Your code attempts to assign new id values to `shp_objects` which is a list, not an object. It should be assigning to a member of that list. Arguably it would be more idiomatic to use `lapply` than a `for` loop in any case. Code follows.

```
species <- "name_of_directory_holding_shapefiles_do_not_add_slash_to_end"

list_shp <- list.files(path = species, pattern = "*.shp", full.names = TRUE,
                   recursive = TRUE, include.dirs = FALSE)

shp_objects <- lapply(list_shp, function(x) {readOGR(dsn=x, layer=ogrListLayers(x))})

# See the row names (IDs)
lapply(shp_objects, function(x) row.names(x@data))

idx <- 0
for(i in seq_along(shp_objects)){
 idx <- idx + 1
 shp_objects[[i]] <- spChFIDs(shp_objects[[i]], as.character(idx))
}

lapply(shp_objects, function(x) row.names(x@data))

# or instead of for loop use lapply and generate unique id string on the fly
shp_objects <- lapply(shp_objects, function(x) {
    new.id <- paste0(x@data$id, sprintf("%03d", round(runif(1, 1, 999)),0))
    spChFIDs(x, new.id)
})

lapply(shp_objects, function(x) row.names(x@data))
```

This gives the following results:

```
> idx <- 0
> for(i in seq_along(shp_objects)){
+  idx <- idx + 1
+  shp_objects[[i]] <- spChFIDs(shp_objects[[i]], as.character(idx))
+ }
> 
> lapply(shp_objects, function(x) row.names(x@data))
[[1]]
[1] "1"

[[2]]
[1] "2"

> 
> # or use lapply and generate an unique id string on the fly
> set.seed(1234)
> shp_objects <- lapply(shp_objects, function(x) {
+     new.id <- paste0(x@data$id, sprintf("%03d", round(runif(1, 1, 999)),0))
+     spChFIDs(x, new.id)
+ })
> 
> lapply(shp_objects, function(x) row.names(x@data))
[[1]]
[1] "28g114"

[[2]]
[1] "28h622"
```